# airflow ingest data from json api doesn't work

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I use google cloud to create a pipeline for ingest data from api by using google cloud composer

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import timedelta

import pymysql.cursors
import pandas as pd
import requests

def get_data_from_api():
    url = "https://de-training-2020-7au6fmnprq-de.a.run.app/currency_gbp/all"
    response = requests.get(url)
    result_conversion_rate = response.json()
    conversion_rate = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_conversion_rate)
    conversion_rate = conversion_rate.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"date"})
    conversion_rate['date'] = pd.to_datetime(conversion_rate['date']).dt.date
    conversion_rate.to_csv("/home/airflow/gcs/data/conversion_rate_from_api.csv", index=False)

def covid_api():
    url = "https://covid19.th-stat.com/json/covid19v2/getTimeline.json"
    response = requests.get(url)
    df = response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df['Data'])
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date 
    df.to_csv("/home/airflow/gcs/data/result.csv", index=False)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'datath',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@once'
}

dag = DAG(
    'Retail_pipeline',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Pipeline for ETL online_retail data',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='api_call',
    python_callable=get_data_from_api,
    dag=dag,
)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='api_covid',
    python_callable=covid_api,
    dag=dag,
)
 t1 >> t2
```

the first task works fine but the second task got failed and I try the second task on jupyter it works fine please help don't know what to do

Comment: Could you provide the logs of the failing task?

Comment: https://www.img.in.th/image/OFK2FT

Comment: I tried the code and I observed that the URL “covid19.th-stat.com” for t2 is not available, thus, most probably this is the cause of the error because the expected data cannot be retrieved. Can you please verify the URL or update for an available one? Then try to run the DAG again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is failing on the `response.json()` step.
There are a couple things you can do to troubleshoot:

1. Output the raw result of the response with like `r.text`. I think this will show you where the error is.
2. If you are still uncertain where the error is after step 1. We should load the result and try to deserialise using native `json` from python.

Comment: I'm new to this airflow. how to output result in a text file

Comment: You can just do `print(r.text)` and it will appear in the logs.